# Jfreechart dynamic charts

Tags: java, dynamic, jfreechart

Please point me in correct direction. Need help.
Requirement to show below dynamic data ( need to refresh the charts every 10 secs).

1. # of items in a queue
2. Age of oldest item in Queue.

I am using Jfreechart, confused about what kind of chart is appropriate for this kind of requirement. Would like few pointers.How about showing both 1 and 2 in the same chart? or else should I show 1 and 2 in separate charts?

Comment: The way you have described it, those are really only two data points. Are you measuring those as a function of another variable, such as time?

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are only two data points and would like to measure based on the time.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [`org.jfree.data.time.DynamicTimeSeriesCollection`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/DynamicTimeSeriesCollection.html), which "adds the ability to append new data and discard the oldest." A [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) is convenient for the periodic updates, as it's action event handler executes on the event-dispatching thread.

Addendum: As it's a time series, the domain axis can be formatted to show the age. An `XYItemLabelGenerator` is an alternative; here is an [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo) using `NumberFormat`. The number of items in the queue can be displayed in the corresponding series' legend.

Comment: Like your idea. would like ti try, only thing I am concerned about showing both data points in the same chart.

Answer (score 0):

> How about showing both 1 and 2 in the same chart? or else should I show 1 and 2 in separate charts?

The answer is: What does your customer want to see?

Is it meaningful to be able to immediately correlate these two data points?

Comment: Tim thanks for your response. Well the customer is confused and don't know what he wants. I am trying something meaningful and helpful. Just want some pictorial representation of the above data points.